# Magento 2.4.0 sort products on product listing by is_salable

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2

I want to products on product list will always be sorted from salable to not salable. Products which have "Add to cart" button should be show firstly.

I tried created plugin as is written in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178061/magento2-sort-products-and-search-result-by-stock-availability :

`//di.xml`

```
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">
            <plugin name="product_sort_by_stock" type="Company\Module\Model\Plugin\Layer"/>
    </type>
```

`//app/code/Company/Module/Model/Plugin/Layer.php`

```
    <?php declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace Company\Module\Model\Plugin;
    
    class Layer
    {
    
        public function aroundgetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject, \Closure $proceed)
        {
            $selectedDirection = 'DESC';
            $collection = $proceed();
            $collection->getSelect()->order('is_salable '. $selectedDirection);
            return $collection;
        }
    }
```

But it not works for me.

Could you advice me how to  sort product collection by `is_salable` attribute? I have Magento 2.4.0 and Elasticsearch 7.9.2

Comment: Can you describe what "doesn't work"? Do you get an error or are results not sorted like you want (and if the latter please show some examples of what you get vs what you expect)

Comment: Doesn't work means that adding the plugin doesn't change sorting products. They are in the same order.  They are not sorted like I want. I expexted that products on list will be sorted as follows:
1. Add to cart
2. Add to cart
3. Out of stock
4. Out of stock

Comment: @eggman Can you please share your final solution? how you have fixed above things with elasticsearch.

Answer (score 3):

You could override this file and do your customization.

Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\SearchResultApplier

I'm also facing the same issue in Magento 2.3.2. This works to me.

Comment: I think it's good place when collection is paginated. Can I do something like this before pagination?

Comment: Hi did you foud solution to later before pagination @eggman ?

Comment: @aravind Yes this file i good place to make customization, but recived bounded number of records from elasticseach (page size). It is necessary to edit request to elesticsearch and it returns all category products. SearchResultApplier makes pagination again.  I have to install module which doesn't use SearchResultApplier and now I have default solution.

Comment: This helped me!